# Tomcat working in http://localhost:8080/ but does not working when try http://localhost:8080/page/home.jsp

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat8

I've created a maven project with spring and hibernate. I configured tomcat 8.5 in this project.
When I tried to run the tomcat server in the first time `http://localhost:8080/` does not work. I searched in google and I found that I needed to do some configuration in tomcat:

**Steps:**

- On Tomcat Server Click on right button> Properties
- In General menu: Click on Switch Location
- The location was changed from [workspace metadata] to /Server/Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost.server

After this configuration, I started the tomcat server again and `http://localhost:8080/` is working now. I can see the Tomcat welcome page

But when I try to access `http://localhost:8080/EventryApp/hello.jsp` its does not work.

The error is:

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
```

In log file is:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Oct/2018:09:42:30 -0300] "GET /EventryApp/hello.jsp HTTP/1.1" 404 1098
```

Could you please help me understand the problem?

Follow my settings files:

**EventryApp/pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>br.com.eventryapp</groupId>
<artifactId>EventryApp</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-CI-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>EventryApp Maven Webapp</name>

<properties>
    <maven.test.failure.ignore>true</maven.test.failure.ignore>
    <spring.framework.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.1.9.Final</hibernate.version>
    <sl4j.version>1.7.2</sl4j.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <hsqldb.version>2.2.9</hsqldb.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                <sourceIncludes>
                    <sourceInclude>**/*.*</sourceInclude>
                </sourceIncludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Configuration which allows JUnit tests to be placed in the same folder as java files -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java/</testSourceDirectory>
                <testClassesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/</testClassesDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <!-- Configuration which allows configuration files (such as xml files) to be placed in the same folder as java files -->
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java/</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>


<dependencies>
    <!-- ********************************************************************** 
         **                 SPRING DEPENDENCIES                              ** 
         ********************************************************************** -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- ********************************************************************** 
         **                 HIBERNATE DEPENDENCIES                           ** 
         ********************************************************************** -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- ********************************************************************** 
         **                 OTHER DEPENDENCIES                               ** 
         ********************************************************************** -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jcl</artifactId>
        <version>${sl4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${sl4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>${hsqldb.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- ********************************************************************** 
        ** TEST DEPENDENCIES 
    ** ********************************************************************** -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

**EventryApp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml**

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>ApplicationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
        <servlet class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

**EventryApp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Enable autowire -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- If you use MySQL Database comment out this bean and let others commented  -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" ></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/eventrydb" > </property>
       <property name="username" value="root" ></property>
       <property name="password" value="" ></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- SQL Server 2012 and 2014 Database drivers and connectivity code -->
    <!-- <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" ></property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=mydb" ></property>
    <property name="username" value="sa" ></property>
    <property name="password" value="abcd@1234" ></property>
</bean> -->

    <!-- Session Factory Declaration -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" ></property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.entities" ></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <!-- SQL Dialect -->
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>

            <!-- SQL Server 2014 Dialect -->
            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop> -->

            <!-- Your required Database Name -->
            <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">eventrydb</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
            <prop key="format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="use_sql_comments">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

 <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" ></property>
</bean>
```

**EventryApp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/EventryApp-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" ></property>
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" ></property>
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

**hello.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
     <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Eventry API</title>
     </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Hello Eventry API</h1>
      </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Check if your application is correctly deployed. Is there any error in the tomcat logs at deployment time?

Comment: No, When I try access the page the tomcat log has no any error.

Comment: I see, but you did deploy the application right?

Comment: How I can ckeck it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all. I simply doesn't matter for testing or developing purposes where your local tomcat is located. I'm working with the standard server location (Use workspace metadata). But it's got nothing to do with your problem.

Second you must configure the base path of your application. Normally this is done when you add your application to your server (e.g. when you are using Eclipse)

If this is not done automatically then you must write the following in your server.xml file

```
<Context docBase="myApp" path="/myApp" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:myApp"/>
```

This makes your application available under "http://localhost:8080/myApp"

Third you need to configure a controller which is handling requests to this url. Mostly you will want to have something like a login formula.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/")
@Scope(value="session")
public class MainController {

  @RequestMapping
  public ModelAndView mainView() {
    ModelAndView mav = getModelAndView("mainView");
    return mav;
  }

}
```

I see that you have two servlet definitions. Do you really want to have more than one context for your app? You might want to unite these two.

Comment: Hi m46, I don't have server.xml, so I need create this file? or this server.xml file is the same from web.xml?

Comment: Hi, you must have a server.xml. If you deploy to a **nix environment you'll find it in the /conf dir. This file is automatically created during tomcat installation. If you have an eclipse windows environment you'll find it in e.g. .metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\conf.